# How to open modal using dynamically added button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am working on Html modal. I took the reference of the following link
[jQuery hunterPopup Demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Bootstrap-style-Popover-Plugin-For-jQuery-hunterPopup/). I am trying to add buttons dynamically using JQuery which will further used to pop up modal. I used following code to add button dynamically.

```
$("#mainTable").append("<button  class='custom-samples-routes' id='popupReturn" + srNumber + "' style='height:30px'" + getRoute + "</button>");
```

I am having 3 buttons by default on screen and they pop up modal without any problem. The problem arises when I added button dynamically and tried to modal using this new button.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    var popupEvent = function () {
    }
    $('.custom-samples-routes').hunterPopup({
        width: '380px',
        height: '270px',
        content: $('#tableContent'),
        event: popupEvent
    });
});
```

Where **#tableContent** is the id of the modal. How can I open modal using newly added button?

Comment: May I suggest setting up a simple jsfiddle? It will help answer your question faster as people have access to the entire thing. Could be because your id isn't unique.

Comment: first u need to make sure if the button clicked fired the function, im afraid you should use $('.sample-routes').hunterpopup() not the   $('.custom-samples-routes')

Comment: Sir, I have corrected my code. It is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it something like below.

```js
var popupEvent = function() {
    alert("Hello")
}
var config = {
    width: '320px',
    height: '200px',
    title: "jQuery hunterPopup Demo",
    content: $('#tableContent'),
    event: popupEvent
}
var counter = 1;
$().ready(function(e) {


    $('#addnewDynamic').on('click', function() {
        debugger
        var _btn = $("<input/>", {
            type: "button",
            value: "Show popup",
            id: "btn_" + counter,
            class: "btn btn-success"
        })

        $("#container").append(_btn);
        $("#" + "btn_" + counter).hunterPopup(config);
        counter++;
    });

});
```

```css
body { background-color:#34BC9D; font-family:'Roboto';}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Bootstrap-style-Popover-Plugin-For-jQuery-hunterPopup/js/jquery-popup.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Bootstrap-style-Popover-Plugin-For-jQuery-hunterPopup/css/hunterPopup.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id='container'>
<input type="button" id="addnewDynamic" value="Add New Button with Popup" style="margin: 20px 0 0 20px;" class="btn btn-default">

        <div id="tableContent" style="display:none">
            <div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Sub Title</div>
                    <div class="panel-body form-inline dept1">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" id="001">Item</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" id="002">Item</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" id="003">Item</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" id="004">Item</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach listener to the document and check if it's element with class `custom-samples-routes`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.custom-samples-routes', function() {
  console.log('Listening')
});

$("#mainTable").append("<button class='custom-samples-routes'>Dynamic Button</button>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainTable">
  <button class="custom-samples-routes">Button 1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you bind the popup *after* you inject the button in the DOM. Your code should look something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {

  // 1. inject button
  $("#mainTable").append("<Button class='custom-samples-routes' style='height:30px'><label class='samples-routes' id='popupReturn" + srNumber + "' style='height:30px'>" + getRoute + "</label></Button>");

  // 2. bind popup
  var popupEvent = function () {}
  $('.custom-samples-routes').hunterPopup({
      width: '380px',
      height: '270px',
      content: $('#tableContent'),
      event: popupEvent
  });
});
```

Also, note that you have a couple typos in the code you posted which might also be a cause of error:

1. There's a extra `"` at the end of the `$("#mainTable").append()`.
2. The button you inject has the class "samples-routes" and the label has "custom-samples-routes". It's probably safer to you the button for the event.